# bash screen command multi-window mode

Tags: linux, bash

I am just wondering if I can attach to few different process and see the output on the same session.

For example I start few process in detach mode

> screen -dm -S process "cp 111 222"
>
> screen -dm -S process "cp 333 444"
>
> screen -dm -S process "cp 666 777"

At the end I want to attach to all of them and the output in one screen, like with *screen -r*
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to start those as separate windows within a single `screen` session, by using something like

```
screen -dm -S process cp 111 222
screen -X -S process screen cp 333 444
screen -X -S process screen cp 666 777
```

(Note lack of quotes; if you quote it, you'll find the created window reports an error along the lines of `Cannot exec 'cp 333 444': No such file or directory`, because it takes the quoted command as the name of an executable, not as a command and parameters.)

Comment: Can I start this in separate processes but in the same window?

Comment: If you attach to a session created in this way, you will find (via `Ctrl-a w`) that it has 3 windows open, each of which is running a `cp`.  Is this not what you want?

Comment: If you want them all to be visible simultaneously, look at the `split` command.  `screen -X -S process split` before each `screen -X -S process screen cp ...`.